# What is the most appropriate translation for this law article?

Tags: translation

In [this Skeptics answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/9287/4727), a user provided a rough translation of a Chinese law article — from [this source](http://www.gov.cn/banshi/2005-08/23/content_25575_2.htm) — about vehicles and pedestrians using Google Translate. So I thought, why don't we provide a good translation?

The Chinese article is:

> 第四十七条　机动车行经人行横道时，应当减速行驶；遇行人正在通过人行横道，应当停车让行。

And Google says:

> Article 47 of the motor vehicle when passing a crosswalk, shall slow down traffic; when a pedestrian is crossing a crosswalk, shall stop to give.

Not the best translation, certainly. What would be a more appropriate translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Article 47: When a motor vehicle vehicle passes through a crosswalk, it should proceed at reduced speed; in the case when a pedestrian is crossing the crosswalk, the vehicle should stop and yield to the pedestrian.

Answer (score 1):

Article 47: A motor vehicle should slow down while passing a pedestrian crossing. When a pedestrian is crossing the pedestrian crossing, one should stop to let the pedestrian pass.

Comment: I rolled back your answer to its first version. (If you think my edits are not valid or they change the meaning, you can do this yourself.)

Comment: For me it didn't really matter whether "pedestrian crossing" is used or "crosswalk". I just mentioned what I originally wrote because there was a new post only because crosswalk is only used in the US. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crosswalk_%28disambiguation%29

Comment: I rolled back because it was your translation after all...

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. You are doing a great job here on SO.

Comment: Thank you! :) You meant CL&U or SE? SO is Stack Overflow... :D

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant CL&U/SE

Answer (score 0):

clause 47: drivers of motor vehicle shall reduce their speed when approaching a pedestrian crossing, and shall bring the vehicle to a full stop where there is a pedestrian crossing.